What's the difference between lossless WEBP with diffrent "quality" value
When encoding an image to WEBP with imagemagick, it's possible to set different quality levels.  (Gimp disable 'quality' when "lossless" is checked).
The image size is significantly different, yet the contents looks identical !
(compared via naked eye).
What does "quality" mean when WEBP is lossless?
magick a.png -quality 5 -define webp:lossless=true a5.webp
magick a.png -quality 99 -define webp:lossless=true a99.webp

size in bytes;
 19018  a-05.webp     # quality 5
 23566  a-99.webp     # quality 99
 19948  a-50.webp     # quality 50
 25956  a-gimp.webp   # all lossless
 47393  a.png         # original


